# Best opening in blind simultaneous chess

Tags: opening, blindfold-chess, simultaneous

I am interested in blind simultaneous chess, where one person plays (blind) vs multiple (non-blind) opponents.

What would be the best openings for either side? I would assume anything slow would be disadvantageous to the blind person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the simul-giver needs to keep the games as different from each other as possible. That means the opening themselves are less important, as long as they are *different* openings.

The simul-takers can cooperate with each other; I recall the following story from [Tim Krabbé's website](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess/lovest.htm):

> It made me think of a story. A grandmaster once played a 10-board blind simul somewhere. Knowing the ropes of blind simuls, he varied his games right from the start, maybe opening two with 1.e4, two with 1.d4, one with 1.b3, and so on. To his suprise, all of his opponents played 1...b6. On the second move, five of them played 2...Bb7, and the other five 2...Ba6. On the third, three of the five players who had played 2...Bb7 now played 3...Bc8 and the other two played 3...Ba6, while three of the five who had played 2...Ba6 now played 3...Bb7, and the other two 3...Bc8. On move 4, the grandmaster saw bishops everywhere. After move 5, he excused himself and went to the toilet where he was happy to find a window big enough to let him through.

---

> I would assume anything slow would be disadvantageous to the blind person.

That makes sense, because there are more pieces on the board. However, if those pieces occupy 'normal' positions, that's usually easier to remember/visualize (from my personal experience, which is limited to a single blindfold game at a time). So if you're taking part in a blindfold simul, and don't want to 'cheat' like in the above story, play a 'weird' opening.

Comment: (+1) I love that Krabbé anecdote! :)